# In k-means or kNN, we use euclidean distance to calculate the distance between nearest neighbours. Why not manhattan distance?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, distance, k-nearest-neighbour, metric

In k-means or kNN, we use euclidean distance to calculate the distance between nearest neighbours. Why not manhattan distance ?

Answer (score 1):

No, KNN is generic and you can use any valid metric you want. For example, cosine distance is another metric that is used frequently. Here is an [implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) in `scikit-learn` where you can choose among several distance options. You can also define your own metric to use.

[K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is slightly different. It really uses Euclidean distance, and it becomes a harder [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_problem) for generic metrics. However, [k-medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering) is a variation of k-means with L1 distance. it has variations such as k-medians (using L1 distance). [k-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) is another generalization of this algorithm where the cluster center is chosen among the data points and you can use any metric with it.